# Blocking Virtual Machine (VMWare) IP on host PC

Tags: virtual-machine, ip, vmware, sniffing, packet

I have a packet sniffer/analyzer running on my host machine which reads packets sent and received between two virtual machines (using VMWare). Both virtual machines' networks are NAT.

The packet sniffer has limits set for certain packet properties. Whenever any limit is exceeded, the IP of the machine is displayed. The displayed IPs should be blocked, and I was thinking of using Windows Firewall on my host machine. However, creating a rule on the firewall and blocking it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any idea why it's not working? Is it possible to block a virtual machine's IP from the host? Or is there an alternative solution to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2):

That is happening because most probably you are applying firewall rules to some other profile rather than applying it on the profile in which VM interface is.

To select the profile for your interface to which firewall rules are getting applied to:

1. Click on Windows Firewall Properties
2. Click the Private Profile tab
3. Click Customize
4. Select the Interface you want
5. Click OK

Comment: All interfaces were already selected..